# Open a Image folder Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my project in mvc4. I have an Image folder and I want to open and list all images in that folder using jquery . I write the following jquery ajax code for that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var URL = '../../Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DG/';
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        success: function (data) {
           $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function () {
                var images = $(this).attr("href");
                alert(images);
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });       
});
```

But this always go to Error function. Can anybody please tell me what is the exact problem. Is there any problem in my URL path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a static folder:

```
var URL = '../../Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DG/';
```

instead you should have a controller that serves images