# Constant error attempting to find images with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Before I begin, I just wanted to say that I know [this question is out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803005/open-a-image-folder-using-jquery), but the answer was unclear, and I don't have enough reputation to comment asking for clarification.  So I apologize about that.

Anyway, my question (and code) is very similar (but not quite identical) to that in the link above.  I'm trying to read the name of each image into an array that I can get into later, but every time I run the script, it returns an error.

```
var images = new Array(30); //I already know there are 30 pictures
var i = 0; 
$.ajax({
    url: "projects/pj",
    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
        $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg), a:contains(.JPG), a:contains(.png), a:contains(.PNG), a:contains(.gif), a:contains(.GIF)").each(function() {
            images[i] = $(this).attr("href");
            i++;
        }); 
    }, 

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

The folder "projects" is in the same directory as the script, just to be clear.

Thanks so much for your help!

EDIT: I just thought I'd add that I've used this technique before for getting picture names, but I didn't try to put them into an array, I just added them to a list.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "content/images",
        success: function(data){
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg), a:contains(.JPG), a:contains(.png), a:contains(.PNG), a:contains(.gif), a:contains(.GIF)").each(function() {
                var images = "content/images/" + $(this).attr("href");
                $('#container ul').append('<li></li>');
                $('<img>').attr("src", images).appendTo($('li').last());
            });
            $('#container ul li').first().addClass('active');
        }
});
```

This one worked.  Not sure why this one does and the one I'm asking about doesn't.

Comment: What error is it returning exactly? Is the one that you from the error alert function or something else?

Comment: What does `get into array later` mean? Ajax is asynchronous so it sounds like you might be trying to access array before ajax has completed. Show how you use array `images` and explain error in more detail

Comment: @ChadWatkins: It's giving me the alert I set in the error function.

Comment: @charlietfl Basically, I'm trying to create the array of image names so that I can assign one of them to be the background image of an element in the page later in the script.

Comment: did you check your browser's debugger?

Comment: @Ven I tried to see what was happening by setting up a couple breakpoints, but all that showed me was how the success function was being skipped.  Are there other tools I can use to dig deeper into the problem?

Comment: I think you should look at the network tab. This is most probably where it's going wrong

Comment: For example, if you don't have a web server running and are using `files:///`, this won't work.

Comment: The only activity showing in the network tab is jQuery being loaded.  Right now, I'm working locally with file:///.  I'll try making the site live and playing with that to see if I can make ajax cooperate.

Comment: @charlietfl: After the ajax bit closes, i.e. after the all the code I posted, I say $('#myDiv').css("background-image", "url(" + images[selection] + ")"), where selection is a randomly generated number between 0 and 29.

Comment: you can force browser security to allow ajax... but not a good idea for your own security. Installing a local server on your machine is very simple and there are numerous ways you can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need** a webserver for ajax requests. Just using your website from `files:///` will **not** work.

Usually, getting to the `error` callback means there's been a *network* error, not a code one (except if you generate the path from code, obviously).

This is why you should try looking into the "network" tab of your browser console, and check to see if these requests are failing -- then why.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without using ajax?

Comment: It probably wouldn't be a good idea. Is installing a webserver impossible for some reason?

Comment: I'm sure it's not impossible, I just don't know what you mean.

Comment: No, you can't do what you want without AJAX. Is there a reason you're not using a webserver?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "use a webserver."  Like, host the files somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this was your question. I meant setup apache, nginx, lighttpd or something else and use `localhost`

Comment: So I have a website.  I don't manage the server because it's hosted by my school, but if I put the files from this project onto my site, would that work?

Comment: I hosted it on my site and it didn't work, but then I added a .htaccess and it worked!